# Why is Unity MouseLook very shaky and jittery?

Tags: unity, camera, mouse, first-person-shooter

I'm working on a first person shooter game.

My problem is that my `Mouselook` script is shaky and jittery when I looking around.

Here is my code:

```
Transform MyTransform;

const string vert_input = "Mouse Y";
const string horz_input = "Mouse X";

public float mouseSensitivity = 100.0f;
public float clampAngle = 80.0f;

void Update()
    {
        the_time = Time.deltaTime;

        ROTX_ROTY.y += (Input.GetAxis(horz_input) * mouseSensitivity * current_speed_offset * the_time); 
        ROTX_ROTY.x += (Input.GetAxis(vert_input) * mouseSensitivity * current_speed_offset_vertical * the_time);

        ROTX_ROTY.x = Mathf.Clamp(ROTX_ROTY.x, -clampAngle, clampAngle);

        MyTransform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(ROTX_ROTY.y, Vector3.up);
        x_rot_transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(ROTX_ROTY.x, Vector3.left);
    }
```

And this is my input settings for `Mouse X` and `Mouse Y`:

[image]

For more explanation: I put my camera inside one of my controller children and if I put it out of controller the issue is still there.

I tried `Lerp`, `Slerp`, `smoothdamp` , `euler` but does not make any difference.

I tried this script for Android and I used a touch instead of a mouse and the result was same.

I tried it on `FixedUpdate` and the result was same.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Here is a [video about my problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gM-d9QpsTjI).

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this problem with just the code shown here. Can you please edit your question to include a minimal complete verifiable example, including how you've configured the `horz_input` & `vert_input` controls in the Input Manager, and the values of / any code modifying the sensitivity and current speed offset parameters?

Comment: Try using FixedUpdate

Comment: I tried ! but it's not working . @Bálint

Comment: What's the type of "the_time"?

Comment: the_time is float !!! @Bálint